Is there definitive confirmation that the Pope sacked Cardinal Tremblay in "Conclave"?
In Conclave (2024), during the papal conclave, Cardinal-Dean Lawrence (played by Ralph Fiennes) receives information suggesting that the Pope may have asked or demanded Cardinal Tremblay (played by John Lithgow), one of the leading candidates for the papacy, to resign during their final meeting before the Pope’s death.
Tremblay faces another controversy: he arranged Sister Shanumi’s transfer to the Vatican, a matter I’ve previously asked about. While Tremblay admits to this action, he firmly denies being sacked by the Pope, dismissing the claim as “absurd.” In contrast, Archbishop Wozniak, who wasn't present at the meeting, claims that the Pope told him afterward that he had sacked Tremblay.
Adding to the confusion, Monsignor Morales, who did attend the Pope’s last meeting, states that he “knows of no reason why Cardinal Tremblay should not be Pope," cryptically noting, “El informe ha sido retirado” (“The report has been withdrawn”). What exactly he means by this is unclear to me.
Does the film or the book it is based on provide definitive information about whether the Pope dismissed Tremblay?

The Pope sacked him, but died before anyone could make the act official. His staff seem to have been in the habit of waiting until the following day before making any proclamations based on his meetings, due to his erratic behaviour and advancing illness, which meant that Tremblay was still able to take over the situation when the Pope died the same day.
The head of the Pope's private household (Archbishop Woźniak) was pretty clear that the Pope told him, later the same day, that Tremblay had been dismissed during that meeting.

‘Very well.’ The Pole took a breath. ‘You remember that on the day the Holy Father died, the last person to have an official appointment with him, at four o’clock, was Cardinal Tremblay?’
‘I remember.’
‘Well, at that meeting, the Holy Father dismissed Cardinal Tremblay from all his offices in the Church.’
‘What?’
‘He sacked him.’
‘Why?’
‘For gross misconduct.’
Conclave by Thomas Harris

Neither Tremblay, nor the only other witness to the meeting itself , Monsignor Morales, the Pope's Private Secretary, were willing to admit that the Pope's final act was to dismiss him. Whatever was said in the room, the Pope died before he could make the act official, and Tremblay then managed to nobble the good Monsignor before he could tell anyone.

‘Listen, Janusz,’ he said. ‘Are you absolutely certain you’ve got this right? I can see how upset you are. But, for example, why hasn’t Monsignor Morales ever mentioned anything about it? He was there in the apartment with us on the night the Holy Father died. He could have brought it up then. Or he could have told one of the other secretaries.’
‘Eminence, you said you wanted the straight facts. These are the straight facts. I’ve been over them in my mind a thousand times. I found the Holy Father dead. I summoned the doctor. The doctor summoned Cardinal Tremblay. Those are the rules, as you know: “The first member of the Curia to be officially notified in the event of the Pope’s death is to be the Camerlengo.” Cardinal Tremblay arrived and took control of the situation. Naturally, I was hardly in a position to object, and besides, I was in a state of shock. But then, after about an hour, he drew me aside and asked me if the Holy Father had had anything particular on his mind when we had supper. That’s when I should have said something. But I was frightened, Your Eminence. I wasn’t supposed to know of these matters. So I just said that he seemed agitated, without going into any details. Afterwards, I saw the cardinal whispering in the corner with Monsignor Morales. My guess is that he was persuading him not to say anything about the meeting.’
‘What makes you think that?’
‘Because later I did try to mention to the monsignor what the Pope had told me, and he was very firm about it. He said that there had been no dismissal, that the Holy Father had not been his normal self for several weeks, and that for the good of the Church I shouldn’t raise the subject again. So I haven’t. But it’s not right, Eminence. God tells me it’s not right.’

Tremblay is supremely confident that Morales will back up his version of events.

Lomeli said, ‘If the report is, as you say, mendacious, perhaps you
could explain why the Holy Father, in his last official act as Pope,
asked you to resign?’
A stir of astonishment went through the room.
‘He did no such thing – as the only witness to the meeting, his
private secretary Monsignor Morales, will confirm.’
‘And yet Archbishop Woźniak insists that the Holy Father told him
personally of the conversation, and that he was so agitated over
dinner when he was recalling it that his distress may have contributed
to his death.’
Tremblay’s outrage was magnificent. ‘The Holy Father – may his name be
numbered among the high priests – was a sick man towards the end of
his life, and easily confused, as those of us who saw him regularly
will confirm: was it not so, Cardinal Bellini?’.

